# Digit number and two characters after the point

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have a number, for example:

```
25297710.1088
```

I need to add a bit between them and leave two characters after the point.
For example:

```
25 297 710.10
```

While I stopped at this:

```
$(td).text().reverse().replace(/((?:\d{2})\d)/g, '$1 ').reverse());
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
    return this.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

From this code I get the following:

```
25 297 710.1 088
```

Where  `$(td).text()`  I get a number from the cell of the row in the table.
If I have numbers, for example:

```
25297710.10
```

then i get:

```
25 297 710.10
```

It's ok.

What I need to do to leave two characters after the point?

Comment: Split the string by dot, then after manipulations add the cut rest to the new string.

Comment: http://numeraljs.com/  You know that ?

Comment: Sergey - I will try this. Thanks.

Comment: Hüseyin Okumuş - I think about it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RegExp to format the number/string. The input is converted to string using the relevant toString method.

```js
function formatNumber(input) {
  return input.toString().replace(/\d*(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})\.(\d{2})\d*$/, "$1 $2 $3.$4");
}

var str = "25297710.1088";
var num1 = 25297710.1088;
var num2 = 2545454545454.2254;
var num3 = 232545454511112.3354122313123123;

console.log(formatNumber(str));
console.log(formatNumber(num1));
console.log(formatNumber(num2));
console.log(formatNumber(num3));
```

Comment: It's not works, because it does not leave two characters after the point and if we have numbers, for example:2545454545454.1054 - not works too.

Comment: Fixed. Try again.

Comment: Good. I update function on  return input.toString().replace(/(\d{2})\d*$/, "$1").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");  But when number: 22000 I got: 22

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do next steps:

1) you have 25 297 710.10

2) you find position of dot symbol ->@pos

3) you replace bits in string in range between @pos and end of your string

4) you cut string after dot to 2 characters

Comment: I'm going to implement this. Thanks